# OBSOLETE - Elections Statistics page for Stack Exchange sites

Tags: app, obsolete, website, elections

> ## Obsolete: The site has been down hard for a couple of years.
>
> Reference:
>
> - [Shog9's answer on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294723/148310)
> - [The GitHub issue](https://github.com/tms/stack-election/issues/3)

[image]

[**The Stack Exchange Elections Statistics Page**](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) is a simple single-page website that displays information on election candidates participating in the Stack Exchange 2011 Moderator Elections. It pulls together information normally found in each candidate's profile as well as their Meta and SE-wide participation information into one single handy site, presenting the information neatly and efficiently, allowing you, the voter, to make the most informed decision possible.

#### Features

- All the information you can usually find on a user's profile, like reputation, badges, age, location etc. pulled into a single central location for easy comparison
- Statistics on Meta and SE network wide activities
- Customisable checklist of interesting or noteworthy badges to watch for for each candidate
- Active tags and tag badges related to them
- Ability to add arbitrary users to the lineup, for comparison with the candidates

And much, much more.

#### Where can I get it?

> ## http://elections.stackexchange.com/

Community members have also been going round posting links to this on each of the site's Meta, so watch out for those too.

#### Browser support

Should work reasonably well on all modern browsers (IE. not Internet Explorer, though you're welcome to try).

#### Contact

Please post bug reports and feature requests (more suggestions on what stats to display always welcome!) here. You can usually find me in the [Meta Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general) if you want to talk. The idea was brought up originally by Benjol on Meta Stack Exchange.

#### Code

This page is written entirely with front-end web development technology. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is the backbone, and the [jQuery template plugin](http://github.com/nje/jquery-tmpl) is used extensively. [Snippets from James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) are used for sorting stuff, and [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) is used for relative time.

[The code is on GitHub at `tms/stack-election`](https://github.com/tms/stack-election)

Comment: please add [ED.se](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/election) too

Comment: For information on the refresh of this being released soon including a link to a dev version see: [Detailed Moderator Election statistics site not updating](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/190132)

Comment: What exactly is Upvote/Downvote? Is that the number of votes the moderator has cast on various questions/answers during his lifetime? Or is it the number of votes he's received during elections?

Comment: @Vek.M1234 The total number of votes cast, exactly as you see on the user's profile

Comment: The links to the elections page seem broken

Comment: @Helmar Yeah. I came here seeking answers.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It doesn't currently seem to recognise Gaming's new election correctly.

It doesn't show up as an active election, but the Gaming option in the "Completed Elections" section actually does load the *current* election so it's sort of working - it makes it hard to find, and also means we can't access the previous election any more (at least, I can't find it).

---

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Also, a few requests that'd be handy, but aren't really important:

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Could we please have support for adding the "Deputy" badge in the noteworthy badges list? It doesn't seem to be recognised when I try to add it.
- [status-obsolete](/questions/tagged/status-obsolete) I don't know if the API exposes it, but showing a user's flag weight along with their other stats could be a nice addition.

Comment: +1 for the feature requests.  Not sure if the bug is still extant; it seems to be working for the current elections.

Comment: The bug and first feature request were done.  Second feature request would be nice but is also covered by the election page itself.

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The Stack Overflow election has just appeared, and they're missing an important badge.  Deputy, at 500 flag weight, might not be considered 'noteworthy' but it's actually *required* in this case:

> For the Stack Overflow election, an eligible candidate for the election must have all of the following badges (note, this is not mechanically enforced):
>
> - Civic Duty *[Present in Noteworthy list]*
> - Strunk & White *[Present in Noteworthy list]*
> - Deputy
> - Convention *[Present in Noteworthy list]*

I propose that these be called out as 'required' badges for the SO election, and that 'Deputy' be added to the 'Noteworthy' list for other elections.  This was also [requested by DMA](https://stackapps.com/questions/2049/stack-exchange-elections-statistics-page/2542#2542).

Comment: Those badges are not required for every site's election -- only a few sites have many uses that have them.

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Would probably be useful to expand the notable badges to include the new Review badges (Steward, Reviewer, Custodian)!

Also number of flags approved and number of delete votes that have been cast if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have access to that information directly from the API, but we can scrape the number of helpful flags from the election page itself...will see what I can do.

Comment: @TimStone, Any chance the code will get put up in GitHub so we can make pull requests?  It looks like a real easy fix to add these 3 badges to the results and they are awesome for helping identify who's already been helping with moderation.

Comment: @BrockAdams https://github.com/tms/stack-election (I guess a link should be added to the page itself!)

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

It would be nice to see one's own or another user's profile analyzed in this manner. It could be used like a "Should I bother running?" self-check.

Obviously there would be no candidate text shown for people who have not come forth but but I like the extra bit of data aggregation that seems like a supplement to the profile page... And even if you don't plan on running you could see how valuable your participation is to the community and where there may be more room for improvement for better participation.

Comment: Exactly what I thought as well - even collecting the data for other users and not during elections on a specific site could be interesting.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please add [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/moderator-candidate-statistics-are-not-available-for-travel) to the list as `http://elections.stackexchange.com/#travel.stackexchange`

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The page seems to be breaking in Chrome for the stack overflow nominations with the following message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". It stops working after the step "Loading User Profile on main site".

Looking at the code it would appear that line 607 is causing problems:

```
userId = +post.find('.user-details a').attr('href').split('/')[2];
```

The reason is that the value of the href attribute as returned by jQuery is qualified with the host name despite that not appearing in the source. From my console window:

```
post.find('.user-details a').attr('href').split('/')
["http:", "", "stackoverflow.com", "users", "92837", "sathya?tab=activity&sort=reviews"]
```

The result of this is a list of user ids containing "NaN".

Comment: Firefox and Safari have problems with the same code.

Comment: Just for record-keeping purposes, this was fixed in the deployed version, and is also fixed in the upcoming rewrite.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Noteworthy Badges" section appears to have a bug on the [wordpress.stackexchange Moderator Candidate Statistics page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#wordpress.stackexchange). It may effect other elections as well, but I am not sure.

Tom J. Nowell, Kaiser, and myself all have [the "Strunk and White" badge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) but the badge is marked red on the elections page.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

See [the most recent Stack Overflow election](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow), for example.  It says, "These are your new moderators", but... who are they exactly?

[image: screenshot of SO 2015 election]

This image makes it seem like codeMagic was a new moderator, when in fact that's not the case as can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/election/6

Comment: Additionally, I get a whole mess of "undefined" and "NaN" as text on the page in Firefox 39.0.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please add [GIS.se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election) to the list! 
thanks :)

Comment: Done! (Clear your browser cache if you don't see it)

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

- Add data about closed and/or deleted questions each person asked
- Add Bicycles to the list. **Update:** Done.

Comment: We *could* add data about the closed questions, but since we don't have metrics for the deleted ones it might be skewed if someone has a lot of closed-but-also-deleted questions.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please add security.SE to the list.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Add a filter to include only candidates who are in the final election, once the primaries are finished.

Comment: Now that we'll be doing all of the scraping on the server going forward, annotating the candidates with their final election phase status shouldn't be that big of a deal.

Answer (score 4):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Please add [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) to the list, [elections there](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election) are already in primaries!

See also MSO [bug report here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/190113/145951).

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
Update: Fixed ([GitHub pull request](https://github.com/tms/stack-election/pull/1)) and deployed. Thanks, Tim Stone!

---

Reference: [elections.stackexchange.com/#english.stackexchange](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#english.stackexchange)
**The credits links point to 404 error pages:**

[image: bad links]

They point to these 404 pages:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone
```

They *should* point to:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150097/yi-jiang
http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone
```

The link in the footer also has this problem.

Comment: Someone pointed this out to me in chat the other day and I forgot to do anything about it, I'll fix it up here in a bit. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 3):

Safari 5.0.3 screws up the general election info. The data seems to be coming through alright in Safari's Inspector, but it isn't displayed correctly:

[image: buggy Safari layout]

Comment: Known problem with Webkit's implementation of the CSS3 column module `-webkit-column-count`, I don't really have a solution to this right now, but I'll try some stuff later

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Update the list of Noteworthy Badges so that it includes all the badges that the Candidate Score uses for tabulating the score.  This will then make it easier to see the specific gaps in their badge earning, and therefore activity on the site.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Could you please also display the **candidate score** and add a <kbd>Sort by: candidate score</kbd> button?

You could receive the data e.g. from there: http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/298418/candidate-score

Comment: This is the same score that's on the official election page, right?  If so, it's probably easier (and more up to date) to just scrape it from that page.

Comment: @BrockAdams Yeah, it should be ideally the same. But the data.se query is indeed sometimes a bit behind... It allows checking the theoretical score of every user at any time, no matter whether there are elections going on at the moment and whether the user is really nominated or not.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[Programmers](//programmers.stackexchange.com) has moved to [Software Engineering](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

The icon on the main page still uses https://cdn.sstatic.net/programmers/img/favicon.ico, but it should be https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/softwareengineering/img/favicon.ico. Since the old link no longer exists, we get "Programmers logo" instead.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please support badges in other languages. In the [recent election on Russian SO](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#ru.stackoverflow), it looks like nobody has any of the badges. However, that is not strictly true.

Indeed, they do not have the Deputy badge, but they do have the 
Участковый badge, so Deputy should be marked.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a straightforward thing to do.  See [this chat thread](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26183907#26183907), for a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
The site is down hard!

**Update; Reference:**

- [elections.stackexchange.com isn't loading on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294719/elections-stackexchange-com-isnt-loading)
- [The GitHub issue](https://github.com/tms/stack-election/issues/3)

---

Both:

- http://elections.stackexchange.com/
  and
- https://elections.stackexchange.com/

Give:

> Site not found: elections.stackexchange.com

(in the title)

And:

> ### Couldn't find elections.stackexchange.com
>
> The Q&A site elections.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet.

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Would it be possible to tabulate this data and sort on columns? It's very useful but a little slow to find the right candidate. I'd especially like to sort on the ratio of up/down votes, edits and close/delete requests.

Comment: Funny you should say that. The original version of this app was a spreadsheet. It's quite easy to obtain that data by looking into either data.stackexchange or using the API yourself

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
Network rep total calculation seems to be incorrect.  For example, it's [currently showing](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#english.stackexchange) my total as 13.3k when the flair calculation (that includes sites >200 rep) says 15k and the total including all sites is higher than that.  I'm not upset, I'm just filing it as a bug report.
Thanks for your site!
[image: profile for WBT on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: Your flair rep is currently 14,958.  This app uses the API, so it doesn't count your 213 rep from Area 51 (API limitation).  Also, most/none of the 100 rep association bonuses count.

Comment: @BrockAdams is correct. The difference is caused by A51 and because the page removes association bonus (so that you can't just join all 200+ sites of the network and suddenly gain 20k+ rep)

Comment: Just to nitpick: You would have to join 200+ sites AND get 100 points of natural rep, on each site, (with one's handy suggested-edit bot, perhaps) to claim the 20K+ rep. (^_^)