# Stack Exchange, Election Assistant

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, elections

For **moderator elections**, this script greatly helps vet and compare candidates.

#### Features:

- Lists candidates in **sorted order**. Find him/her in a repeatable, predictable, location every page visit.
- Click on a jump-table row to **instantly scroll to that candidate.**
- **Save a bookmark** that opens the page **to that candidate's entry**, every time.
- **Like, Hide, or Reject** a candidate.  Save your data between page visits and between tabs.
- <del>Provides **direct links** to a candidate's entry on the [*Stack Exchange Moderator Candidate Statistics* (SEMC)](https://stackapps.com/questions/2049/elections-statistics-page-for-stack-exchange-sites) page.</del> (Unfortunately, [that site has been down for a great many months now](https://stackapps.com/a/7519/7653).)
- If you open one of those SEMC links, **the script automatically scrolls to the targeted user** (even while the SEMC page loads and settles).
- If you downvoted a candidate in the primary, then those users are auto-rejected when you visit the primary page.
- Works on all SE Election pages. <sub>(Not tested on Non English sites, but should work except for any formatting issues.)</sub>

#### Screenshots:

[image: Jump Table]

[image: Jump Table in action]

#### Install:

(Note that this script requires ***Tampermonkey***, ***Violentmonkey***, or a userscript engine that supports `@require` and all the `GM_` functions used. GM-4+ will not be supported at this time.)

## [<kbd>Click to Install</kbd>](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-Election-Assistant/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%20Election%20Assistant.user.js)

#### Source code:

Is on GitHub at [BrockA/SE-Election-Assistant](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-Election-Assistant).

You may also make bug reports, pull-requests, etc. there.

#### Reference:

- To get to the election pages, add `election/` to the site's home address.
  For example: `http://biology.stackexchange.com/election/` .
  This goes straight to:

  - Any current elections, or
  - It shows the last election if the site has had only one, or
  - It shows a list of all elections that have been held for the site.
- Also, <del>find a list of all site's last, or current, elections on [the *Stack Exchange Moderator Candidate Statistics* main page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/)</del> (when/if it comes back online).

Comment: The avatar of one of the candidates of [the current Worldbuilding election](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/2) breaks the layout of this for some reason.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, fixed with version 1.4.